# Go to a div with jquery steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-steps

I am using some jquery steps plugin on my page. Whit this code, i can go to the next or the previous div.

If i click the `#modify_contact` button, how can i go to the `#step-2` div? I dont copy the html oce, because its just divs with id-s, nothing extra.

```
    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
          allBackBtn = $('.backBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $('#user_vnev').focus();
      }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  });

  allBackBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content");
    var curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id");

    var currStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().children("a");
    var prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");

    prevStepWizard.trigger('click');
    currStepWizard.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
```